# How to get unique identifier while executing code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, vb6

I'm looking for a way to solve my problem :

I have a C# MVC web application that uses a VB6 DLL.

In this DLL, there is a class that is common for all users and I would like to change this architecture.

Is there any possibilities in Class_Initialize function to get an unique identifier to set an array with this id and the instance ?

My goal is to not add this id in all function call.

This allow me to get the correct instance anywhere in the code.

I can use Windows API function or others...

For example, DLL A has ClassA and create ClassB that is in DLL B. The ClassA can be created by an exe application or by c# web application and add an ID in ClassA by setter function. In ClassB constructor, I would like to get ClassA ID. It could be possible if ClassB has a setter and when ClassA creates ClasseB, pass id by the setter. But the problem is that ClassB could be created by ClassZ, herself created by ClassY, herself... created by ClassA

My program have 95 projects and 1000 class. The solution might be to pass id by setter in all classes but it's very difficult to make it so I look for "undergroud" solution by working with memory for example...

If in ClassB I could retrieve ClassA and id it would be fantastic for me

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please provide code

Comment: you will have no other solution than pass a guid or some other kind of identifier  from the parent instance to the child instance, within the constructor or in a setter, as you sad

Answer (score 1):

You can create a unique guid with the following VB6 code. You might then be able to use this in your class(es) to track the instance you need. I'm not entirely sure of that, though, given the sparse amount of information provided with no code in the original post.

```
Public Type GUID
   Data1 As Long
   Data2 As Integer
   Data3 As Integer
   Data4(7) As Byte
End Type
Public Declare Function CoCreateGuid Lib "OLE32.DLL" (pGuid As GUID) As Long

Public Function GetGUID() As String
  Dim udtGUID As GUID
  Dim sGetGUID As String

  On Error Resume Next
  If (CoCreateGuid(udtGUID) = 0) Then
    sGetGUID = String(8 - Len(Hex$(udtGUID.Data1)), "0") & Hex$(udtGUID.Data1) & "-" & _
               String(4 - Len(Hex$(udtGUID.Data2)), "0") & Hex$(udtGUID.Data2) & "-" & _
               String(4 - Len(Hex$(udtGUID.Data3)), "0") & Hex$(udtGUID.Data3) & "-" & _
               IIf((udtGUID.Data4(0) < &H10), "0", "") & Hex$(udtGUID.Data4(0)) & _
               IIf((udtGUID.Data4(1) < &H10), "0", "") & Hex$(udtGUID.Data4(1)) & "-" & _
               IIf((udtGUID.Data4(2) < &H10), "0", "") & Hex$(udtGUID.Data4(2)) & _
               IIf((udtGUID.Data4(3) < &H10), "0", "") & Hex$(udtGUID.Data4(3)) & _
               IIf((udtGUID.Data4(4) < &H10), "0", "") & Hex$(udtGUID.Data4(4)) & _
               IIf((udtGUID.Data4(5) < &H10), "0", "") & Hex$(udtGUID.Data4(5)) & _
               IIf((udtGUID.Data4(6) < &H10), "0", "") & Hex$(udtGUID.Data4(6)) & _
               IIf((udtGUID.Data4(7) < &H10), "0", "") & Hex$(udtGUID.Data4(7))
    GetGUID = LCase$(sGetGUID)
  End If

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your code, but this function return an ID always different

Comment: Exactly.  It returns a unique id on every call.  From your post, it seemed that you were looking for a unique id that you could assign to instances of your classes?  When a class is created, have it create a unique id, or pass in a unique id, then you need to use that to keep track of your class instances.  You'll need to provide more info (and code!) than the current generic descriptions in your post if you want assistance in the keeping track of classes.